# Find file(s) recursively and filter them by their path matching specific substring(s)

Tags: find

Complete Linux newbie and need help with command to find filenames, list their respective paths, and then further filter that result set by only the paths that contain a specific substring(s).

For example I have a filename identified as `someFile.txt`. This filename can exist in multiple directories:

E.g. `/some/directory/path/good/someFile.txt` and `/some/directory/path/bad/someFile.txt`

Using find I can return a list of all paths containing that file, but I'd like to return ones that only contain 'good' in the path name as well. Whitelisting in this example is preferable as there are many variable path names, but I know the ones containing the term 'good' are acceptable.

This is what I have that works:

```
$ find . -type f \( -name someFile1.txt -o -name someFile2.txt\)
```

I've also tried the following to no avail:

```
$ find . -type f \(-name someFile1.txt -o -name someFile2.txt\) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -rl 'good'
$ find . -type f \(-name someFile.txt .... | xargs -0 grep 'good'
$ find . -type f \(-name someFile.txt .... | xargs -0 egrep 'good|real_good'
```

Comment: No need for `xargs` - you just want to know if it's in the path, right? `find ... | grep good`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-path` test with `find`:

```
find . -path '*/good/*' -type f \( -name someFile1.txt -o -name someFile2.txt \)
```

The `-path` test works like `-name`, but the pattern is tested against the complete pathname of whatever file `find` is currently considering.

The way I'm using the test above will ensure that only files with the names `someFile1.txt` or `someFile1.txt` that are located somewhere beneath a directory called `good` is returned by `find`.

If the files are supposed to reside in the `good` directory, and not in a subdirctory beneath it, then use

```
find . -type f \( -path '*/good/someFile1.txt' -o -path '*/good/someFile2.txt' \)
```

or something similar.

Obviously, if you are looking for actual files called `someFile1.txt` and `someFile2.txt`, you would be using the pattern `someFile[12].txt` rather than two separate tests.

From comments, it's clear that you may want to use

```
find . -type f \
    \( -ipath '*realgood*' -o -ipath '*real_good*' \) \
    \( -name someFile1.txt -o -name someFile2.txt  \)
```

Comment: I apologize that I wasn't entirely clear in my example as I tried to generalize it too much. Something closer to that I'm dealing with looks as follows: /somefilepath/moresubdirs_someDir_good_1_2/fileName1.txt or /somefilepath/moresubdirs_someDir_real_good_1_2/fileName1.txt. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: @C_Squared So use `*good*` or `*_good_*` instead of `*/good/*` with `-path`?

Comment: I also believe I found something that works through trial and error. $ find . -type f  \( -name someFile.txt -o -name someOtherFile.txt\)  | egrep -i 'realgood|real_good'

Comment: @C_Squared I wouldn't use `grep` on pathnames (as they can theoretically contain newlines). What you are showing there is the equivalent of `\( -ipath '*realgood*' -o -ipath '*real_good*' \)`.

Comment: your ipath solution worked perfectly. Thanks!